# How to add a one-side border and background into one drawable?

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` and to that in the `android:background` property I currently have a xml drawable which changes the `ImageButton` background color when pressed. This is all good but I also want to add a top border to each of these `ImageButton`'s.

Here's a sample image I created to better get my point across.
These buttons will also have an active state which indicates the current active button and I can set that as a drawable using Java code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple drawables to get your work done. You can have drawable icons/images with the top border and the same without the top border and use the setBackgroundResource method to switch image backgrounds. (I believe you want to show the images with top border as currently selected tool icon, right?).

As you're going to construct several such image buttons like a toolbox, you'll have to make sure their selection states are controlled properly. If one image-button is selected all others should show the unselected drawable.

I threw together some codes and built this small example. Hope you'll find it useful.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageButton imButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imButton1);
        final ImageButton imButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imButton2);
        final ImageButton imButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imButton3);

        imButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {   
                imButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon1_selected);
                imButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon2_unselected);
                imButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon3_unselected);
            }
        });

        imButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {   
                imButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon1_unselected);
                imButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon2_selected);
                imButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon3_unselected);
            }
        });

        imButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {   
                imButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon1_unselected);
                imButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon2_unselected);
                imButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon3_selected);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is it's Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bbb"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imButton1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imButton2"
        android:background="@drawable/icon1_unselected" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/imButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon2_selected" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imButton2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imButton2"
        android:background="@drawable/icon3_unselected" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

A screen-shot of the image buttons working.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating two seperate drawable xml files such that one has a top border and white color background and other one has same color border with a bit grey background. Then in the `selector` xml file all I had to do was assign each of these xml files to their respective states and problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:bottom="-6dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#6c6c6c" />

            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you may use view for border like that,you put this in your all side of your image view then you can see,

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000" />
```

whatever color you want to use. thanks